# MSVC: Optimizing away x * 0.f

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some functions which contain some `x * 0.f` expressions. Those are optimized away if I use the compile flag [/fp:fast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fp-specify-floating-point-behavior). But apparently it is not possible to set this flag with `#pragma float_control(...)` - Not sure why. Because of that I tried to use the [`__assume(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/assume) intrinsic to trigger the optimization step for certain variables - but according to the assembly output that did not work. Anyone has another idea how to trigger fp:fast semantics for certain functions?

Example: https://godbolt.org/g/KDQw9X

Comment: The docs for #pragma float_control make it look like this requires both float_control and fenv_access. And that you need to set both float_control(except, off) and fenv_access(off), at least the docs say that is required to go to a fast model.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Oh my... You are right. Not sure how I missed that part. If you put it in an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I missed the important part in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45ec64h6.aspx)...

Here is a [snippet](https://godbolt.org/g/ZbeNUH) which works for MSVC and GCC

```
// GCC
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define USERLIB_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
// MSVC
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define USERLIB_PRAGMA(x) __pragma(x)
// Fallback
#else
#define USERLIB_PRAGMA(x)
#endif

// GCC
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_BEGIN \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(GCC push_options) \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(GCC optimize("fast-math")) \

#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_END \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(GCC pop_options) \

// MSVC
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_BEGIN \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(float_control(except, off, push)) \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(float_control(precise, off, push)) \

#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_END \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(float_control(pop)) \
    USERLIB_PRAGMA(float_control(pop)) \

// Fallback
#else
#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_BEGIN
#define USERLIB_FAST_MATH_END
#endif

float a(float x) {
    return 0.f * x;
}

USERLIB_FAST_MATH_BEGIN
float b(float x) {
    return 0.f * x;
}
USERLIB_FAST_MATH_END

float c(float x) {
    return 0.f * x;
}
```